# what is the application private directory in windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am porting a Cordova/Phonegap application from Android to Windows Phone 8.

What is the Directory which is private to my Application only, which means that cannot be used by any other application.

In a nutshell, The equivalent that for android is **file:///data/data/mypackage**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're are looking for

```C#
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder)

---

Also from the MSDN,

You can access files in the local app data store using the "ms-appdata:///local/" protocol. For example:

```HTML
<img src="ms-appdata:///local/myFile.png" alt="" />
```